# Haskell: Monadic construct within lambda function

Tags: haskell

I have this snippet of a function:

```
mapM (\x -> do t' <- t; return $ strSwop "if0" ("if" ++ show x) t') [0..(n-1)]
```

With

```
strSwop :: String -> String -> String -> String
t :: IO String
```

It works as expected  but I don't like the IO construct withing the lambda.
How can it be written differently?
I come out of the monad just to be wrapped again next line. Feels ugly.

If I do it this way:

```
mapM (\x -> t >>= strSwop "if0" ("if" ++ show x) t) [0..(n-1)]
```

It complains (obviously) about the return signature of strSwop :(
strSwop is just a string replacement function.
Is there a way to correctly write this?
Thanks.

**-- EDIT --**

Just figured it out ...

Works out:

```
mapM (\x -> liftM (strSwop "if0" ("if" ++ show x)) t) [0..(n-1)]
```

Comment: Off-topic: On stackoverflow, it is generally considered polite to accept the answer (click on the tick below the answer's score), which helped you solve the problem. It helps not only the user who answered it, but it also helps you, because it provides other users with an incentive to answer your questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest `liftM` or `<$>`

```
import Control.Applicative
mapM (\x -> strSwop "if0" ("if" ++ show x) <$> t) [0..(n-1)]
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I just actually figured this out seconds ago. I did it with liftM exactly as you suggested. It worked out: mapM (\x -> liftM (strSwop "if0" ("if" ++ show x)) t) [0..(n-1)]

Comment: @r.sendecky: If an answer helped you, you should click the check mark underneath it to accept it :)

Answer (score 2):

Let's simplify your code step by step.

```
mapM (\x -> do t' <- t; return $ strSwop "if0" ("if" ++ show x) t') [0..(n-1)]
```

Start by breaking off the pure code - let's convert `[0..(n-1)]` into a list of `[String -> String]` using currying:

```
mapM (\f -> do t' <- t ; return (f t)) $ map (\x -> strSwop "if0" ("if" ++ show x)) [0..(n-1)]
```

Now `do t' <- t ; return (f t)` is pretty common - that's just `fmap f t'`

```
mapM (\f -> fmap f t') $ map (\x -> strSwop "if0" ("if" ++ show x)) [0..(n-1)]
```

And `\f -> fmap f t'` is just `\f -> flip fmap t' f` or `flip fmap t'`

```
mapM (flip fmap t') $ map (\x -> strSwop "if0" ("if" ++ show x)) [0..(n-1)]
```

Cleaning up the pure half: `\x -> strSwop "if0" ("if" ++ show x)` is the same as `\x -> strSwop "if0" $ ("if" ++) (show x)` which is the same as `\x -> strSwop "if0" . ("if"++) $ show x` which is the same as `strSwop "if0" . ("if"++) . show`

```
mapM (flip fmap t') $ map (strSwop "if0" . ("if"++ ) . show) [0..(n-1)]
```

Now let's fuse the two parts back together.  `mapM f . map g = sequence . map f . map g = sequence . map (f . g) = mapM (f . g)`:

```
mapM (flip fmap t' . strSwop "if0" . ("if"++) . show) [0..(n-1)]
```